# Disable emoji input on TextField

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard, emoji

Can I disable emoji soft keyboard input for `TextField`?

Currently using `KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Ascii)` as keyboard options, but it doesn't work. I'm still able to enter emoji.

[Documantation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/KeyboardOptions#keyboardType()) says this doesn't guarantee it will work with all keyboards.

My question:

Is there any other way to disable emoji, or I have to filter input manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a good way to filter input from the keyboard like there was in traditional Android. Any use of regex to remove values will place your cursor in the wrong spot, especially if someone is editing the string from the middle.

Instead, what I've seen suggested ([one sample answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65654054/1703677)), is to show an error when the user inputs invalid content.

I used a regex filter [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45894101/1703677) to show an error when emoji is present.

```kotlin
    fun containsEmoji(emailStr: String?) =
        Pattern
            .compile("\\p{So}+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
            .matcher(emailStr.toString()).find()

    var emailText by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
    var containsEmoji by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Column {
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            value = emailText,
            onValueChange = {
                emailText = it
                containsEmoji = containsEmoji(it.text)
            },
            label = { Text(text = "Your message here") }
        )
        if (containsEmoji) {
            Text("Please remove emoji!")
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to prevent to typing emojis in the textfield, you can use the above function `containsEmoji` and prevent the text from updating with `onValueChange = { if( !containsEmoji(it.text) ){ emailText = it }},`

Answer (score 0):

You can disable emoji's in TextField, outlinedField in jetpack compose by using keyboard type

`keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions( keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password) keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions( keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email)`